# Find referenced assemblies of a assembly that is referred in extension project

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, vs-extensibility

I have an add in. While using the addin, I need to generate the details of referenced assemblies in the project. I can able to get the assemblies details by following way.

```
VSProject vsproject = _project.Object as VSProject;
References ref = vsproject.References;
```

and I am able to get version and other details of that assembly. now I need to get the dependencies of this assembly. 
for EX: if A is the assembly that is referred in a project. and assembly B is needed to use assembly A (i.e A is depends on B). Now I need the details of assembly B also, how to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found solution to this. we can achieve this by following way.

```
Assembly a = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom("path of the dll");
var y=a.GetReferencedAssemblies();
```

now you can get the all dependent assemblies details.